# Issue while downloading a file from server (Save works fine but Open does not open the file)

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am trying to download a file uploaded from a location on server. Here is the code i am using
to download a file

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
Response.End();
```

Here i have files of various extensions i.e a file can be a **jpg/pdf/doc/txt** i am currently setting `ContentType` to `image/jpg`.

When i try to download a file than it gets Saved properly and than can be opened from the physical location where it is saved but the Open does not work and the file is not downloaded i get the error as shown in the picture.

[image]
[image]

This issue is even when i try to Open a file of type `jpg` so i dont think it is something to do with `ContentType`

Kindly help.

Comment: you should try removing the Response.end(); Also, do you have some kind of no-cache directive ? It could make problems with IE.

Comment: @jbl Yes the issue is with IE please help.What do you mean by `no-cache directive` i did not understand.Removed `Response.End();` but that did not help either

Comment: you should check that you do not have lines likes Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"; or Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); Also, adding size in the Content-Disposition would help...

Comment: @jbl i dont have anything as `no-cache`

Comment: you should not set incorrect Content-Type - either specify something generic (like octec-stream) or skip it.

Comment: Also, you should try Response.WriteFile instead of Response.TransmitFile (still without the Response.End)

Comment: FWIW, the proper content type is image/jpeg, not image/jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specified `Content-Type` as `octet-stream` and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Most typically this problem happens on Internet Explorer with disabled caching (the file is downloaded to temp folder and then deleted before you click Open). See [IEInternals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/10/03/internet-explorer-cannot-download-over-https-when-no-cache.aspx).

How to determine this: launch [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) and look for caching headers in the file download response.

If the response includes `Cache-Control: no-cache` header, you will have to modify your code to either override it with `Cache-Control: private` or change the code where you disable it to exclude the handlers/pages/actions that generate the files (sometimes asp.net has problems overriding `Cache-Control` headers and thus I usually use the second approach).